# development desktop in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, application-development, python

how do I create programs for ubuntu, with the same ease that I have with visual studio express on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Ubuntu Software Center \ Development \ IDEs (Integrated Development Environment) you will probably find what you are looking for. The following are a few of the best: (at least in my opinion)

- Geany supports most programming languages, but does not have features such as a designer, intellisense, etc.
- Qt Creator probably has the most ease-of-use features, but only supports C++.